# How to place an Array like a row in a List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How do I place an Array like a row in a List?

For Example:

```
 string[] Myarray = new string[] {"A","B", "C"};
 List<string> MyList = new List<string>() { Myarray[0], Myarray[1], Myarray[2] };
```

Comment: `MyList = Myarray.ToList();`

Comment: You're `List`  needs to be the same type of the things you're putting into it. Try `<string[]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
```

This is a list view of the array, the list is partly unmodifiable, you can't add or delete elements. But the time complexity is O(1).

If you want a modifiable a List:

```
List<String> strings = 
     new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"}));
```

This will copy all elements from the source array into a new list (complexity: O(n))

Comment: Is this .NET/BCL? `Arrays.asList` and `ArrayList<string>`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I'm new and I have only used javascript and BlueJ for my classes. I know what it is, and I believe its not BCL but its how I did it in one of my projects for class.

Comment: I am unsure if it is or if its FCL, but I don't have many years of experience so I don't know. I am also trying to learn about javascript and BlueJ while attempting to help people.

Comment: Since the asker had used the tag `[c#]`, I did not think JavaScript or BlueJ/Java was relevant to his question.

Comment: I what i mean by my last comment is while trying to learn javascript and bluej i'm also on my spare time learning c#

Comment: well actually I'm trying to learn a lot of coding languages but mainly I deal with BlueJ and javascript